# How can I edit read-only text after pasting?

Tags: text-properties, read-only-mode

I want to create a buffer where some parts are editable, but others are not. I'm using the `read-only` string property to do this, e.g.:

```
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*scratch-demo*")
  (insert ";; you can edit me\n")
  (insert (propertize
           ";; but you cannot edit me\n"
           'read-only t)))
```

If I paste the second line into a buffer in fundamental mode, I can edit it.

```
this buffer is in fundamental mode
;; but you cannot *foo* edit me
```

However, if I paste the second line into an emacs-lisp-mode buffer, I cannot edit it.

```
;; this buffer is in emacs-lisp-mode
;; I cannot modify the line below:
;; but you cannot edit me
```

How can I ensure users can edit text, which has been yanked from read-only portions of my buffer?

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't see the problem you mention.  Maybe I miss the recipe. I did this, in a session from `emacs -Q`:

   a. In buffer `*scratch*` I typed your code and evaluated it.

   b. I visited buffer `*scratch-demo*`.  The text of the second line was read-only (could not modify it).  I copied the text there using `M-w`.

   c. I visited a buffer in Emacs Lisp mode and yanked the copied text, using `C-y`.  I had no problem modifying the yanked text, including the part from the read-only portion.

   d. I did the same thing in a buffer in Fundamental mode - same effect.
2. If you have trouble with this kind of thing, have a look at function `insert-for-yank` and variables `yank-handled-properties` and `yank-excluded-properties`, to get the properties you want and not get the properties you do not want, respectively.

   See also functions `remove-yank-excluded-properties` and `insert-buffer-substring-as-yank`.

   See the Elisp manual, node [Yanking](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Yanking.html) for details.